# Should #process callback use #default_value or #value when expanding an element?

Tags: 7, forms

### Background

The '#process' callback on a form element is called within `form_builder()`. It can be used to expand an element into sub-elements.

This is how e.g. the 'radios' or 'checkboxes' elements work: They behave to the outside as a single form element where the value is an array. But internally they are expanded to separate 'radio' or 'checkbox' sub-elements.

Optionally, there can be a '#value_callback' that acts as the counterpart of '#process'. This way, values are "translated" between the per-sub-element level and the super-element level.

My observation from `form_process_radios()` is that #process callbacks should use the #default_value from the parent element to populate the #default_value of the newly created sub-elements.

### Question

I am writing ajax-powered elements that should expand into a different tree of sub-elements depending on the current form value. So not the `$element['#default_value']` but the `$element['#value']` or `$form_state['input']` or `$form_state['values']`.

So in this case should I write a '#process' callback that looks into `$element['#value']` instead of `$element['#default_value']`?

Note: I might figure this out for myself and just use "whatever works". On this platform I would love to see an answer that actually makes it all sound logical. Which is more than just "whatever works".

Another nice thing would be examples in existing code in core or contrib.